# Script to replace last slash in the mount point

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, fstab, replace

I'm trying to do a script to delete the last **"/"** in the mount point inside of the fstab.

I create this shell script, but, I'm not happy with the result. I wonder if anyone knows how to replace with awk?

I want go from this:

```
/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix/     ext4    defaults        0 0
```

To this:

```
/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix     ext4    defaults        0 0
```

I have this problem in several servers, with several filesystems, and the monitoring system that we use, is not friendly with the last /.

My script is this:

```
fsmp="/urano/fix/AIX_MLs"
lastc=`grep -i $fsmp /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/"`
filesystem=`grep -i $fsmp /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}'`
1part=`grep -i $fsmp /etc/fstab | awk '{print $1}'`
rest=`grep -i $fsmp /etc/fstab | awk '{print $3" "$4" "$5" "$6}'`
if [ "$lastc" = "/" ]
then
  woslash=`echo $filesystem | awk -F/ '{OFS="/";NF--;print $0;}'`
  echo "$1part $woslash $rest"
fi
```

Comment: that looks like the number one in the variable name `1part` -- don't think that's valid; hopefully it's a copy/paste error for something like "ell" `lpart`?

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
$ x="/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix/ ext4 defaults 0 0"
$ echo "$x" | awk '{gsub(/\/$/,"",$2);}1'
/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix ext4 defaults 0 0
$
```

Using gsub, replacing the slash at the end if present.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is:

```
awk '{ if ( substr($2,length($2)) == "/" ) $2=substr($2,1,length($2)-1) }1' <<< "/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix ext4 defaults 0 0"
```

Result:

```
/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: Fair point Jeff, I've amended the solution.

Comment: Excellent!, you simplified my script in one line! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last slash from the `<dir>` field in `/etc/fstab` file (Note that there could be root `/` directory presented by single slash):

Let's say we have such `/etc/fstab` contents:

```
/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix      /urano/fix/      ext4      defaults      0      0
/dev/sda1       /      ext4      defaults,noatime      0      1
```

---

With **awk**:

```
awk '$2~/.\/$/{ sub(/\/$/,"",$2) }1' /etc/fstab
```

The output:

```
/dev/mapper/vgurano-lvfix /urano/fix ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/sda1              /             ext4      defaults,noatime      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the specific context of fstab, try:

```
perl -pe 's!(?<=\S)/(?=\s)!!'
```

Explanation: remove any `/` that is preceded by a non-space-char and followed by a space-car